# Refresh cache in cmus

Tags: music-player

I started using [cmus](https://github.com/cmus/cmus) recently. After adding a music directory if I change any tag of any music files like album name etc. the info in cmus doesn't change. Even if I do `:clear` and then again `:add ~/Music`. How do I refresh this cache in cmus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Just needed a `update-cache` command.

Comment: `update-cache` doesn't work for me until I execute `:clear` and `:add .` again. So I recommend everyone to check both ways: first, try to update the cmus cache and if it doesn't solve your problem, try using `:clear`, adding the music again and then, if it doesn't show the correct metadata, try updating the cache again. It should solve it.